# Lines in the External Monitor Display

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, vga

I'm hoping you can help me.

I got a new **Lenovo Thinkpad T430** for work. I use an external monitor, attached via vga cord, and I'm having a problem: I get little horizontal lines on the monitor. It's most noticeable where there is blank white space. It's almost the same effect at looking out a window and seeing a faint steady rain falling straight down (but on the monitor, the effect is horizontal.

I've gotten the **same effect on two different monitors**, so I don't think it is an external monitor issue. I've also tried solving for the **ground loop issue** by plugging everything in to an adapter with only two prongs, or running the laptop on battery. Also tried moving all the different wires away from each other.

**Different refresh rates and different resolutions also make no difference.**

What could be the issue? Is there a problem with my laptop's video card? I updated the drivers on that, also.

I am at wits end! I read all day on this thing and I'm going cross-eyed! I only have the vga input and USBs.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Cables

- Try to replace the VGA cable

#### If your get the same in your laptop screen then =>

- Its the graphic card its loose open your laptop find the graphic chip and heat it up with a heat gun put a bit preacher on it its a temporary fix..
- Link: [Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJlgPbELL0E)

Answer (score 0):

we deployed these at work, every single one has the issue you describe.  get a DP++ to DVI cable (or whatever your monitor supports).  the plug for this is right next to VGA port on the left side of your laptop.  this should fix your issue.